# adding unique code automatically PHP

Tags: php

I have this some codes:

```
?>
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("db_akademik");

$query = "SELECT max(nim) as idMaks FROM tb_mahasiswa";
$hasil = mysql_query($query);
$data  = mysql_fetch_array($hasil);
$nim = $data['idMaks'];

//mengatur 6 karakter sebagai jumalh karakter yang tetap
//mengatur 3 karakter untuk jumlah karakter yang berubah-ubah
$noUrut = (int) substr($nim, 6, 3);
$noUrut++;

//menjadikan 201353 sebagai 6 karakter yang tetap
$char = "201353";
//%03s untuk mengatur 3 karakter di belakang 201353
$IDbaru = $char . sprintf("%03s", $noUrut);

?>
```

it works. but when I added some records until 3 (003) or 4 (004), it stopped and not changed (if the last record 003, it still 003).

what's wrong? is it about reloading the page? because when I kept continue, it worked again.

Comment: Be aware that you should not connect to database using root account on your "live" website. Your root account should have a password. Finally, youre using old mysql connector which is more prone to SQL injection attacks and you should probably use mysqli instead if possible.

Comment: I will change to the mysqli later. I need to fix the codes first until it works right.

Answer (score 0):

If 2 query runs together, they may get the same `max(nim)` value. Then they would have generate the same `$IDbaru` to insert. If `nim` happens to be your primary key of the table, the later insert query will surely fail.

I'd recommend:

1. Use a simple integer as your table id
2. Using `auto_increment` with it. That means if you don't specify the `id`, server will generate it for you without duplication.
3. Alter the table's `AUTO_INCREMENT` value to match your id strategy. For example,

   `ALTER TABLE tb_mahasiswa AUTO_INCREMENT = 201353000;`

Comment: I think it can't be changed to auto increment because nim is unique codes (varchar).

Comment: Then you should properly lock table from writing before the select query and unlock after the insert. Please reference: [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html)